# What program can I open Etcher with?

Tags: etcher

I downloaded the Linux version of Etcher from [Balena website](https://etcher.balena.io/#download-etcher) . and after that When I click on it, it doesn't open and doesn't install, how can I solve this problem? What program can I open it with?

[image]